# Calling .js function between body tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Sorry for my bad english ;-)

I work around with "Slider Captcha" on my perl Forum Software.

In the .js file there the code is ...

```
(function($) {
$.fn.slideToCAPTCHA = function(options) {
    options = $.extend({
        handle: '.handle',
        cursor: 'move',
        direction: 'x', //x or y
        customValidation: false,
        completedText: 'You\'re human!'
    }, options);

    var $handle = this.find(options.handle),
        $slide = this,
        handleOWidth,
        xPos,
        yPos,
        slideXPos,
        slideWidth,
        slideOWidth,
        $activeHandle,
        $formEl = $slide.parents('form');

    startSlider();

    $handle.css('cursor', options.cursor)
        .on('mousedown', function(e){ slideOn(e); });

    function startSlider() {
```

And i cal the function between < /body > and < /html >

```
<script>$('.captcha').slideToCAPTCHA();</script>
```

Now my question...
... how can I call the. js function within < body> and < /body > or within < head > and < /head >?

The div class in the html document is ...

```
<div class="captcha"> ... bla .... bla....</div>
```

lg Christian

Answer (score 0):

To call the function, you will need to have an event handler - you could use `onclick=dummyCall()` for instance and make a dummy function such as

```
function dummyCall(){
   $('.captcha').slideToCAPTCHA();
}
```

to run it -even though I'm pretty sure there's a better way to do this..
BTW you're english is not that bad ;D

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you should just move the script tags like so:

```
<html>
  <head>
    ..
  </head>
  <body>
    ..
    <script>
      ..
    </script>
    <script>$('.captcha').slideToCAPTCHA();</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thx for help

In Perl i must use "\" bevor "$" ... so it work and call the funktion!`

```
  <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    <!--
      \$('.captcha').slideToCAPTCHA();
    //-->
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

lg XTC